# How to terminate the process created by wkwebview?

Tags: objective-c, macos, wkwebview

In creation of Wkwebview, it create two process, one for loading web content another for networking.... when multiple wkwebview's are created multiple process get created. How to reuse the process again? or is there any way to dealloc the wkwebviews created.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: while creating application based on wkwebview, consider a table view with some data list, on clicking each cell, we need to show the contents in a wkwebview, it creates 2 process for loading and networking, again when clicked another cell from list this add 2 more ending up with 4 process... if we have 1000's of cell like that think of the process that is created on the system, it will affect the performance.

Comment: Do you think that or did you test it? Do you think that you are a better developer than the developer of `WKWebView`?

Comment: i have tested with a sample application... do you think that creating a process of each wkwebview is good? if multiple process keep on increasing it will affect the performance and result in memory warning at particular time.
Finally, " Do you think that you are a better developer than the developer of WKWebView?" - if you know the answer for the solution please provide, such kind of question i wont entertain.

Comment: I would trust in `WKWebView`. The number of "processes" does not change anything. You can have them.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of network processes used by multiple `WKWebView` instances by assigning a shared `WKProcessPool` instance to property `configuration` of your WKWebView object.

```
static let processPool = WKProcessPool()

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.processPool = YourClass.processPool
webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
```

To help terminating the content process of a WKWebView object, use this:

```
webView?.stopLoading()
webView = nil
```